# how to get live event on sonata Admin and Select2 jquery

Tags: sonata-admin, jquery-select2

I added this [example](http://code.runnable.com/UmuP-67-dQlIAAFU/events-in-select2-for-jquery) to my sonata admin page.

I try to get the live event on select2 change status, but I can't get the event: no js error, nothing in the console.

How do I get the event on select2 in a sonata-admin edit page?

**EDIT**: the page contains multiple select2 html tags. I am trying to get events for all of them. I edit a collections M2M.

Comment: EDIT: the page contains multiple select2 html tag. I try to got event for all of them. I edit a collections M2M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use [livequery](https://github.com/hazzik/livequery/) plugins

```
$('.myClass').livequery(function() {
    $(this).on("change", function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    })
});
```